# how to hide a div on mouseleave from 2 divs in jquery?

Tags: jquery, menu, mouseleave, jquery-hover

the question might be a bit wired but in other words i have a menu (see [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/patrioticcow/fmTnh/1/))

when i hover over a div i get a drop down. when i mouseleave the drop down disappear. so far so good.

the problem is that i want the menu to stay open if the mouse is hovering over the drop down also.

```
ex: if($elem).not(":hover"){..}
```

some code:

```
<div class="top_menu_item">
    <div class="hover_item">
        <a href="#">TEST</a>
    </div>
    <div class="drop_item" style="display: none;">
        <div>
            <a href="#">My test</a>
        </div>
        <div class="">
            <a href="#">Add test</a>
        </div>
        <div>
            <a href="#">Remove test</a>
        </div>
    </div>

$(document).ready(function () {
    var elem = new Array();
    var len = $(".hover_item").length;
    var i = 0;
    while (i < len) {
        elem[i] = $(".hover_item:eq(" + i + ")");

        i = i + 1;
    }
    $.each(elem, function (key, val) {
        hoverFunc(val);
    });

});

function hoverFunc($elem) {

    $elem.hover(function () {
        if ($elem.next().is(":hidden")) {
            $elem.next().slideDown("fast");
        }
    });

    $elem.mouseleave(function (e) {
        // here should be :  if the mouse is not hovering over the dropdown, then
        $elem.next().slideUp("fast");
    });

    $elem.next().mouseleave(function (e) {
        $elem.next().slideUp('fast');
    });
}
```

if someone can re-Fraze my question to say what i mean please do so.

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need javascript to do that: [CSS solution](http://jsfiddle.net/fmTnh/2/).

Just add the submenu (`.drop_item`) as a child element to the trigger element (`.hover_item`) and add some CSS:

```
.drop_item { display: none; }
.hover_item:hover .drop_item { display: block; }​
```

Comment: CSS3 transitions (googling that works) will make it look smooth

Comment: +1, but please add your css solution here, don't let your answer die with the link.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out.

Added mouse hover events for the nextElem. Also cleaned up the variables to be more efficient, instead of referencing the $elem.Next(), just set

```
var nextElem = $elem.Next()
```

and added this

```
  nextElem.hover(function () {
    if ($elem.is(":hidden")) {
        $elem.slideDown("fast");
    }

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fmTnh/3/