# is it possible to make a expandable menu?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a menu items, which contains list of items. when i click on menu item, list of items should visible. i can do so by using jquery, using '.on' method. is it possible to achieve this using only css or css3?

Comment: IMO, CSS is not the best option when you need to click on something to get the result.

Comment: @john can u pls suggest me the way how i can solve this?

Comment: @shreedhar you must show what you have tried?

Comment: @VisioN yes i agree with u, but i just wanted to know the way how it can be done without js.

Comment: Do a little homework first shreedhar: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=css-only+menus

Comment: i hav done that, by using jquery. if u want i can post it.

Comment: @shreedhar CSS makes sense when you need to show sub menus *on hover*. I haven't seen CSS solutions with *on click*.

Comment: @Diodeus The OP talks about displaying elements *on click* but not *on hover*.

Comment: @VisioN the OP can modify the code to suit his own needs, .on and .hover is pretty much the same to me, just that .on is pretty longwinded.

Comment: @RenoYeo Man, have you read the question?

Comment: i just want to kno whether can it be done without using any js or jquery.

Comment: @VisioN "is it possible to achieve this using only css or css3?" oh, oh. i apologise :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was just posted, someone provided a solution using css. here is the link. Check it out.

[how to hide a div on mouseleave from 2 divs in jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10804073/how-to-hide-a-div-on-mouseleave-from-2-divs-in-jquery/10804243#10804243)

Here's the jsfiddle they referred to. http://jsfiddle.net/fmTnh/2/